# How to address "The constructor ChromeDriver(Capabilities) is deprecated" and WebDriverException: Timed out error with ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options, mutablecapabilities

I'm trying to config the default download directory as below, it's works correctly but I'm having two issues :

```
    String exePath = "src\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    String downloadFilepath = "U:\\Data\\Download";
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

1. It's telling me that **The constructor ChromeDriver(Capabilities) is
   deprecated**
2. When I replay the test several times it happens to have a Webdrive TimeOut exception

   ```
   juin 13, 2018 5:23:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
   INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
   Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
   System info: host: 'PB02-VD037', ip: '10.143.73.85', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
   ```

Comment: what is your chrome version and chromedriver version?

Comment: Chrome : Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chromedriver : 2.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *ChromeOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *ChromeOptions* object as follows :

```
String exePath = "src\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
String downloadFilepath = "U:\\Data\\Download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.merge(cap);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```