# Common options object for all browser option classes in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, desiredcapabilities, mutablecapabilities

I was earlier using DesiredCapabilities class to create a generic method for setting all capabilities of the browser, using an external file(key=value format). Here's my code

```
public DesiredCapabilities setWebDriverCapabilities(String browser) throws IOException {

    switch (browser) {
        case "ie":
            capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().internetExplorer();
            break;
        case "firefox":
            capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
            break;
        case "chrome":
            capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().chrome();
            break;
        case "edge":
            capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().edge();
            break;
        case "safari":
            capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().safari();
            break;
        default:
            capabilities = null;
    }

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String FS = File.separator;
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("src" + FS + "test" + FS + "resources" + FS + browser + ".capabilities"));
    Set < Object > keys = prop.keySet();
    for (Object k: keys) {
        String key = (String) k;
        capabilities.setCapability(key, prop.getProperty(key));
    }
    return capabilities;
}
```

I found out that its recommended to use Options classes as some of the capabilities classes are going to be deprecated. So I am trying to replace this method with a different method that would work for all Options classes

- FirefoxOptions
- ChromeOptions
- InternetExplorerOptions
- SafariOptions
- EdgeOptions

I cannot find a common object type for all the classes mentioned above so that I can create a similar method in which I was using DesiredCapabilities.

I want to return a common object type from this new method so that I can use it for all driver initialization
e.g.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(setOptions());
driver = new FirefoxDriver(setOptions());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *ChromeOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *ChromeOptions* object as follows :

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.merge(cap);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to address “The constructor ChromeDriver(Capabilities) is deprecated” and WebDriverException: Timed out error with ChromeDriver and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841374/how-to-address-the-constructor-chromedrivercapabilities-is-deprecated-and-we)