# How to pass the capabilities and options into Firefoxdriver using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, desiredcapabilities, mutablecapabilities

I have this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "gecko/linux/geckodriver");

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", true);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3);
options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0);
```

Now I have two different constructors:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

and

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

How can I pass them both (capabilities and options) into the `driver`? By the way, the IDE is telling me that `FirefoxDriver(capabilities)` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *FirefoxOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *FirefoxOptions* object as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "gecko/linux/geckodriver");

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", true);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.merge(capabilities);
options.setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3);
options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to Merge Chrome driver service with desired capabilities for headless using xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671884/how-to-merge-chrome-driver-service-with-desired-capabilities-for-headless-using/47672910#47672910)
- [How to address “The constructor ChromeDriver(Capabilities) is deprecated” and WebDriverException: Timed out error with ChromeDriver and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841374/how-to-address-the-constructor-chromedrivercapabilities-is-deprecated-and-we/50841549#50841549)

Comment: it yells me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden: frozen value=2, requested value=3`... what can I do?

Comment: @assembler That error is related to the _Key_ / _Value_ pair which you are passing as `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` / `0`. But this answer is to cater to your need to _pass the capabilities and options into Firefoxdriver_

Answer (score 0):

you can pass capabilities into `firefoxoptions constructor`  as below :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "gecko/linux/geckodriver");

   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   profile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost");
   profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", true);

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(capabilities);

set profile to firefox options
   options.setProfile(profile);
   options.setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
   options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3);
   options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0);
pass firefox options as parameter to create driver
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```