# FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer error using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium Maven in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, geckodriver

So i am learning selenium and jenkins integration using java and maven.
I had issues with chrome and jenkins and was told i should try the firefox webdriver.
So this is what i did.
However i get the following error when i run the build on jenkins:
Can anyone help me with this? My script runs fine locally on the IDE.

I am also using a mac 10.13.6 (High Sierra),
Firefox 70,
Geckodriver v 0.26.0 ,
3.141.59,
Java eclipse ID and
Maven 3.6.2

Please help and thanks!

## 1) JENKINS LOG

```
Started by user Eamo
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 59937
[Test] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.13.jar:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.2/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.2/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /Applications/apache-maven-3.6.2 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.36.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 59937
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/pom.xml clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< SeleniumTest:SeleniumTest >----------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SeleniumTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SeleniumTest ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
1575090370363   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/3n/x7zhpjbj00z7bm533_6x264r00008b/T/rust_mozprofileNeahYN"
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1575090375045   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 62.465 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   startBrowser(Eamon.EamonTest): connection refused(..)

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-29T21:07:17-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/pom.xml to SeleniumTest/SeleniumTest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SeleniumTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/pom.xml is not inside /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test/Users/Eamon/eclipse-workspace/Test/; will archive in a separate pass
channel stopped
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

## 2) My Code

```
public class EamonTest {

    public String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
    String driverPath = "/Users/Eamon/Desktop/geckodriver";
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void startBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

    }

    @Test
    public void navigateToUrl() {
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void endTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
1575090370363   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/3n/x7zhpjbj00z7bm533_6x264r00008b/T/rust_mozprofileNeahYN"
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1575090375044   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1575090375045   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the usage of **deprecated** *constructor* of [**FirefoxDriver**](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) *Class* as follows:

In the current version of *Selenium v3.141.59* the constructor **`FirefoxDriver(Capabilities desiredCapabilities)`** is deprecated.

[image: desiredcapabilities]

---

### Solution

You need to use the [`merge()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) method from [MutableCapabilities](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) *Class* to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type object into *FirefoxOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *FirefoxOptions* object as follows :

```
@BeforeTest
public void startBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.merge(capabilities);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to Merge Chrome driver service with desired capabilities for headless using xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671884/how-to-merge-chrome-driver-service-with-desired-capabilities-for-headless-using/47672910#47672910)
- [How to pass the capabilities and options into Firefoxdriver using Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494915/how-to-pass-the-capabilities-and-options-into-firefoxdriver-using-selenium-throu/57495469#57495469)
- [How to address “The constructor ChromeDriver(Capabilities) is deprecated” and WebDriverException: Timed out error with ChromeDriver and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841374/how-to-address-the-constructor-chromedrivercapabilities-is-deprecated-and-we/50841549#50841549)